# wlan0 interface fails to fetch IP with udhcpc

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, android, dhcp

I am using USB Wireless Adaptor of Realtek in Android Lollipop with RTL8192DU driver. I am able to scan the wireless network using `iwlist wlan0 scan` command . And I tried to connect to an open network and fetched the ip using `udhcpc` ,the output was bit confusing. I got the ip for the wlan0 interface as usual

```
root@sabresd_6dq:/system/lib/modules # busybox udhcpc -i wlan0               
udhcpc (v1.22.1) started
Sending discover...
Sending select for 192.168.43.206...
Lease of 192.168.43.206 obtained, lease time 3600
```

But when the checked the netcfg,the wlan0 interface is up with no ip assigned.

```
root@sabresd_6dq:/system/lib/modules # netcfg
wlan0    UP                                    0.0.0.0/0     0x00001043 
lo       UP                                    127.0.0.1/8   0x00000049
```

How is this possible? I have specified the interface while running the udhcpc command since it takes eth0 as default....

When I issue netcfg wlan0 dhcp I am getting the ip also static ip is also working. Why udhcpc is not working...? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to get the IP with the below command:

```
netcfg wlan0 dhcp
```

Go for this command instead of `udhcpc -i wlan0`.